# How to update and fetch data of mysql table in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysqli, laravel-5

i created one view page using laravel 5.2, in that page created one table and fetch data from mysql database. and give dynamic drop down button for Edit and Delete. when i click on delete it will delete the corresponding row from the table.That i done and working properly. I want to do the Edit part. When i click on Edit option it will redirect to one form where i need to fetch all the details from corresponding row into form text field and we can edit the things , when we click on save button it will update the data to the mysql table. 
Here i am not able to fetch the details of corresponding row into the form text field. Can anyone help me to do that.
my view page "userAdmin.blade.php" is

```
 @extends('app')

@section('content')


    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
            <li class="active">user information</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="templatemo-content">

            <h1>View/Edit user information</h1>

            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>

                        <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" bgcolor="#fff8dc">
                            <h3>Select User :</h3>
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>User ID</th>
                                <th>User Desc</th>
                                <th>Contact Name</th>
                                <th>Contact Email</th>
                                <th>Time Zone</th>
                                <th>Active</th>
                                <th>Last Login (GMT+05:30)</th>
                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>

                            {{--{{ UserController::getIndex() }}--}}
                            @foreach($name as $nam)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->userID }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->description }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->contactName }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->contactPhone }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $nam->timeZone }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        @if($nam->isActive == '1')
                                            Yes
                                            @else
                                        No
                                            @endif
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{ date('Y/m/d H:i:s',($nam->lastLoginTime)) }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {{--@if ( in_array($nam->isActive, array('Yes','No')) )--}}

                                            <div class="btn-group">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Action</button>
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                                                </button>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                    {{--@if ($nam->isActive == 'Yes')--}}
                                                        <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acceptModal" data-bookingid="{{ $nam->userID }}"><a href="{{ url('user/add/'.$nam->userID) }}">View/ Edit</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    {{--@endif--}}
                                                    <li><a href="{{ url('/user/delete/'.$nam->userID)}}">Delete</a></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </div>
                                        {{--@endif--}}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        {{$name->links()}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <a href="{{ url('user/add') }}"> <input type="submit" id="add" name="add" value="Edit" class="button"></a>

                </br>




    <h4>Create a new User</h4>
    <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('userAdmin') }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 margin-bottom-15">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userID" value="{{ old('userID') }}" placeholder="Enter User ID">
            </div>
            <div class="row templatemo-form-buttons">
                <div class="submit-button">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New</button>

                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();
        } );
    </script>
@endsection
```

and Controller page "userController.php" is

```
  <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Rahul vp
 * Date: 12/05/16
 * Time: 11:06 AM
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Faker\Provider\DateTime;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests\createUserRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public $type = 'User';





    public function getIndex()
    {

        $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);
    }

    public function getData()
    {

        $name = DB::table('user');
        return view('user.add')->with('name', $name);
    }

    public function userInsert()
    {
        $postUser = Input::all();
        //insert data into mysql table
        $data =      array('userID'=> $postUser['userID']
        );
        //  echo print_r($data);
        $ck = 0;
        $ck = DB::table('user')->Insert($data);
        //echo "Record Added Successfully!";
        $name = DB::table('user')->simplePaginate(10);
        return view('user.userAdmin')->with('name', $name);


    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        DB::table('user')->where('userID', '=', $id)->delete();
        return redirect('userAdmin');
    }

}
```

then the Editing page where i need to fetch data for updation "add.blade.php"

```
   @extends('app')

@section('content')

    <div class="templatemo-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="{{ url("/") }}"><font color="green">Home</font></a></li>
                <li class="active">View/Edit User</li>
            </ol>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="panel panel-success">
                        <div class="panel-heading">View/Edit User Information</div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                                    <ul>
                                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('accountAdmin') }}">
                                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User ID</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">

                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userID" value="{{ old('userID')}}" placeholder="Enter User ID">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Active</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('isActive') }}" name="isActive" >
                                            <option value="1">Yes</option>
                                            <option value="0">No</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">User Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value="{{ old('description') }}" placeholder="Enter the description">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactName" value="{{ old('contactName') }}" placeholder="Enter Contact Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Phone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="contactPhone" value="{{ old('contactPhone') }}" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Contact Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="contactEmail" value="{{ old('contactEmail') }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Notify Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="notifyEmail" value="{{ old('notifyEmail') }}" placeholder="Enter E-Mail Address">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Time Zone</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('timeZone') }}" name="timeZone" >
                                            <option value="0">GMT+05:30</option>
                                            <option value="Inactive">xyz</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Authorized Group</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('distanceUnits') }}" name="distanceUnits" >
                                            <option value="0">all</option>
                                            <option value="1">Km</option>
                                            <option value="2">Nm</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Login page</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('firstLoginPageID') }}" name="firstLoginPageID" >
                                            <option value="0">Main Menu</option>
                                            <option value="1">Liter</option>
                                            <option value="2">IG</option>
                                            <option value="3">ft^3</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Maximum Access Level</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" value="{{ old('maxAccessLevel') }}" name="maxAccessLevel" >
                                            <option value="3">New/Delete</option>
                                            <option value="1">Read/View</option>
                                            <option value="2">Write/Edit</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">
                                            Save
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

then route.php is

```
    Route::any('userAdmin', 'UserController@getIndex');
Route::any('user/add', 'UserController@getData');
Route::any('user/delete/{id}', 'UserController@delete');
Route::post('userAdmin', 'UserController@userInsert');
Route::any('user/add', function()
{
    return view('user/add');
});
```

Anyone please help me to do this. response are appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Your laravel code doesn't follow the common practices or the right way to use laravel.

Please have a look into Resource Controllers
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers

Also Eloquent Models
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent

Now let's try to solve your problem, add these to your routes

```
//to show edit form and fetch passed user id info from db
Route::get('user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@edit');

//to get the edited info and save it to db
Route::get('user/update/{id}', 'UserController@update');
```

Now create a model called user by running this command from your project directory:

```
php artisan make:model User
```

Now add these in your controller with other use statements

```
use App\User; /* User model */
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException; /* find or fail error exception class */
```

Now add these to your controller

```
// Show Edit page.
public function edit($user_id)
{
    try{
        //Find the user object from model if it exists
        $user= User::findOrFail($user_id);
        //Redirect to edit user form with the user info found above.
        return view('add',['user'=>$user]);
    }
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $err){
        //redirect to your error page
    }
} 

// Update user
public function update(Request $request, $user_id)
{
    try{
        //Find the user object from model if it exists
        $user= User::findOrFail($user_id);
        //Set user object attributes
        //the $request index should match your form field ids!!!!!
        //you can exclude any field you want.
        $user->description = $request['description'];
        $user->contactName = $request['contactName'];
        $user->contactPhone = $request['contactPhone'];
        $user->timeZone = $request['timeZone'];
        //Save/update user.
        $user->save();

        //redirect to somewhere?
    }
    catch(ModelNotFoundException $err){
        //Show error page
    }       
}
```

In your edit view you can access the retrieved user by doing

```
$user->description //$user->[attribute name]
```

Since you are not using blade, I believe you can do this, wherever you have old(...) replace it with old(...) || $user->... 
**except select tags**

example:

```
value="{{ old('contactName') || $user->contactName }}"
```

for select tags I will give you one example and you need to do the rest by yourself

```
<select class="form-control" value="{{ old('timeZone') || $user->timeZone}}" name="timeZone" >
    <option value="0" {{ $user->timeZone == "0"? 'Selected':''}}>GMT+05:30</option>
    <option value="Inactive" {{ $user->timeZone == "Inactive"? 'Selected':''}}>xyz</option>
</select>
```

Good luck.
Upvotes will be appreciated!

Comment: yeah it is same as add/view. In userAdmin page am creating only userID, remaining things i need to add from the edit/View page. For that i need fetch the corresponding userID and other data from the table to the form.

Comment: The edit function is getting all the data by finding the user with id passed from table.

Comment: from where you are taking user_id?

Comment: in userAdmin page  <li data-toggle="modal" data-target="#acceptModal" data-bookingid="{{ $nam->userID }}"><a href="{{ url('user/add/') }}">View/ Edit</a> what i need give ? , need to change something?

Comment: For edit you need to modify this `<a href="{{ url('user/edit/').$nam->userID  }}">View/ Edit</a>`

Comment: can you tell instead of this what i need write in  my userAdmin page, and from where getting that user_id?

Comment: when i click on edit/view option getting error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `user` where `user`.`id` = jagana limit 1)"

Comment: Got to your User.php in App folder and add this line `$primaryKey = 'userID';` inside your User class.

Comment: i didn't understand. how to add this inside User.php?. want to create new class?

Comment: First you need to delete user.php inside your app folder, then run this commnad `php artisan make:model User` then Open User.php located inside your app folder. After this line `class User extends Model {` add `$primaryKey = 'userID';`

Comment: how we are passing the object $user to add.blade.php page?

Comment: in my project artisan command is not working for make model class. i will send the code that contain in my model

Comment: <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $table = 'user';
    /**
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'accountID'
        , 'userID'
        , 'userType'
        , 'roleID'
        , 'password'
        , 'gender'
        , 'contactName'
        , 'contactPhone'
        , 'contactEmail'
    ];
protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token', ];}

Comment: After `class User extends Authenticatable {` add `protected $primaryKey = 'userID';`

Comment: that is working now, but the code you are given is for insertion, it's not for updation, can you tell how to write the code for update data